# Probability of Selecting a Server

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

This problem is related to randomly assigning servers to user and it is generalized based on $N$ users and $K$ servers.

> Each of $N$ users requesting a certain website is assigned to a given
>   server out of $K$ servers. Suppose that this assignment is done for each
>   user independently by selecting one of the $K$ servers uniformly at
>   random. The question is: What is the probability that there are no
>   servers that are no assigned any users?

I wasn't sure how to approach this problem. I was trying to do something like 
$$P[\text{all users have a server}] = \prod_{i=0}^{K-1} \frac{(K - i)}{K}$$ This would be the probability of picking a different server.

Comment: Please format your question using [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: You have to assume also a probability $q$ of finding the server busy.

Comment: In my opinion I would reduce the problem to that:  Throwing $N$ balls (users) to $K$ cells (servers) find the probability that no cell is empty. The answer to this is $\binom{N-1}{K-1}$.

Answer (score 2):

There is unfortunately no closed form for the probability, unless you consider expressions in terms of [Stirling Numbers of the Second Kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) closed form.

There are $K^N$ equally likely functions from the set of users to the set of servers. To count the favourables, we count the number of onto (surjective) functions. The simplest explicit expression is obtained by Inclusion/Exclusion. The number of surjective functions is
$$K^N -\binom{K}{1}(K-1)^N +\binom{K}{2}(K-2)^N-\binom{K}{3}(K-3)^N+\cdots.$$

Comment: Please, can you look at my answer?

Comment: You subtracted $2^5+2^5+2^5$ from the total (and then subtracted a further $3$).  Call the servers A, B, C. Your first $2^5$ was meant to count the cases where A  was not used, But included in the count were the two cases where B is also not used, and where C is also not used. The second $2^5$ included the cases where A is not used, and where C is not used. So when you find the sum $2^5+2^5$, you are double-counting the case where neither A nor C is used. Similarly, adding the last $2^5$ involves double-counting. My subtraction of $3\cdot 1^5$ at the end  takes care of the double-counting.

Comment: A simple way to see that two subtractions are not right is to take $N=K=$. Two subtractions give answer $0$, which is not right. Subtraction then addition gives $6$, which is correct.

Comment: I see now. You are just right. Thx!

Comment: I've edited the my answer. By the way, do you have your own langueage to solve such problems (by reasoning in terms of functions or some special, but always the same objects [like balls and containers])?

Comment: There is a kind of uniform discussion in the article *The Twelvefold Way* (Wikipedia). I tend to attack each problem as if it were new, although here Inclusion/Exclusion is so standard that it was just a matter of recalling.

Answer (score 2):

I was curious about Andre's answer and I looked at particular example. Namely $K=3, N=5.$

First of all we set servers and users in order and we get that there are $3^5$ options.

So there are two situations where we have no assigend servers.

$(\star)$ One server is without any user. Choice of the server gets us $\binom{3}{1}$ and all users goes to the other two ones. Hence we get $(3-1)^5.$ But we have to exclude the situation when all goes to one server. There are two such situations, but write it $\binom{2}{1}(3-2)^5.$

$(\Delta)$ Two servers are without any user. Choice of two servers without users gives us $\binom{3}{2}$ and all users goes to last one. Hence $(3-2)^5=1^5.$

Your question is about situation where no servers are free of users. Hence the resut is just complement of these two situations above. Namely

$$3^5-\overbrace{\left[\binom{3}{1}(3-1)^5-\binom{2}{1}(3-2)^5\right]}^{\star}-\overbrace{\left[\binom{3}{2}(3-2)^5\right]}^\Delta=3^5-\binom{3}{1}(3-1)^5+\binom{3}{2}(3-2)^5.$$ As we are interested in probability we have to divide it by $3^5.$

It looks like Andre's answer, but using my way of reasoning, it is not easy (for me) to guess the general formula. Maybe doing larger case line $K=4,N=6$ would give more apparent result.